# Sorting to fixed placeholder targets with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a fixed list of slots (sortable drag/drop targets) that need to receive sortable items. The list is grouped into a few sections. It looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is be able to drag/sort the stories across the different slots, as opposed to dragging the slots themselves.

The number of slots for each category is fixed (e.g., there can only be 2 stories in the Opinion category). And stories can be dragged from one category to the other.

I've tried it a few ways... using a single sortable list, using multiple lists, sorting the slots but making it seem like only the stories were sorting. Nothing works quite right.

Is it possible to drag-and-sort child elements across parent elements?  In this case, the story being the child and the slot being the parent.

Or does anyone have a suggestion for another approach?

Update: Here's a JSFiddle example that shows what I'm trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/xzmKZ/6/

```html
<div id="slots" class="block">
  <h4>Top Stories</h4>
  <ul id="sort1" class="slot-group">
    <li class="slot">
        1. <span class="story">This is a Story</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="slot">
        2. <span class="story">This is another Story</span>             
    </li>
    <li class="slot empty">
        3. <span class="story">Yet a Third Story</span>             
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Opinion</h4>                
  <ul id="sort2" class="slot-group">
    <li class="slot empty">
        4. <span class="placeholder">Select a story below</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="slot empty">
        5. <span class="placeholder">Select a story below</span>             
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h4>More Stories</h4>                
  <ul id="sort3" class="slot-group">
    <li class="slot empty">
        6. <span class="placeholder">Select a story below</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="slot empty"
        7. <span class="placeholder">Select a story below</span>             
    </li>
    <li class="slot empty">
        8. <span class="placeholder">Select a story below</span>             
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
h4 { font-weight: bold; margin: 0 0 5px; }
.slot { background: #eee; padding: 5px; margin: 0 0 5px }
.placeholder { color: #aaa }
```

```js
  // Initialize sortable
  $("#sort1, #sort2, #sort3").sortable({
    items: '.slot span',
    containment: '#slots',
    axis: 'y',
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: '.slot-group',
    cancel: '.placeholder'
    });
  $("#slots").disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make each of the categories their own ul.  Then you should pass a selector into the connectWith option:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brian3f/UNXQh/):

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but that just allows the slots to be dragged from one list to another. It doesn't solve the 2 main objectives: drag the stories (not the slots) and keep the number of slots in each category fixed. (So that a 3rd story can't be added to the Opinion category, for example).

Comment: Ah, then my answer is of no help to you.  I think you might need to write more code, I would look into using the draggable and droppable interactions.  They should allow you to keep the slots (as drop targets) while just dragging the elements (draggables).